# How to Strikethrough text in Row A25 to D25 if Cell f25 has any value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, strikethrough

In Google Sheets, I am trying to write up a formula, or use conditional formatting where if Cell F25 has any text or value it will strike through any content in the range of A25 to D25.

Answer (score 0):

Use CF `Custom formula is`

```
=$F$25<>""
```

And apply range `A25:D25`. See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi there.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have worked.  I cannot seem to find a way to insert an image of exactly what I did.  I do have another conditional formatting that is based on the same Range to color code it as you see.  I don't believe this would be an issue.  Would it?

Comment: Here is the image I took https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nrskoTWQ9qwn0WmeFHDYjYPE05bEhbOV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> Try this [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KK_gk-uRZMrZlL6Z9Dl2_BitZYdajaMC4KLp6CB2aM/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=$F25<>""
```

See how to [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en)
[image]

Comment: Hi there.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have worked.  I cannot seem to find a way to insert an image of exactly what I did.  I do have another conditional formatting that is based on the same Range to color code it as you see.  I don't believe this would be an issue.  Would it?

Comment: Here is the image I took https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nrskoTWQ9qwn0WmeFHDYjYPE05bEhbOV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I updated the link in the answer take a look [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KK_gk-uRZMrZlL6Z9Dl2_BitZYdajaMC4KLp6CB2aM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can't actually view the conditional formatting to see the change you did as it is view only.  Can you tell me what code change you made.

Comment: Make a copy go to File > make a copy